# How to create a camera view + a button to capture the photo in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying to find a solution for an android app which I can have both camera preview and a button created with Xamarin Forms (XAML) that when I click that button photo should automatically save in device gallery. After 2 days of research the only best solution I found is [this](http:////https://github.com/UNIT-23/Xam-Android-Camera2-Sample/tree/master/Camera2Sample/Camera2Sample). Can someone please help me achieve this?

[image]

Comment: what is wrong with the solution you found?  Or just using the Media plugin?

Comment: @Jason The above image is not from the solution I found. How the solution I found work is when it tap on the camera preview it fires the event to capture the image. But I want to do it with a button added in the page. And no I don't want to use the media plugin because what it does is opening a new camera page. But I want is within my page

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view) , it implements creating camera preview , i just add the function of take picture and save into gallery .Call messaging center in forms project and get camera instance in android project ,

Call back of Picture Taken

```
public void OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
    {
        camera.StopPreview();

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        Java.IO.File dataDir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);
        if (data != null)
        {
            try
            {
                TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                var s = ts.TotalMilliseconds;
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(dataDir + "/" + s + ".jpg");
                outStream.Write(data);
                outStream.Close();
            }
            catch (Java.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            catch (Java.IO.IOException ie)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine(ie.Message);
            }
        }
        camera.StartPreview();
    }
```

Check my [sample](https://github.com/ColeXm/CameraSample) on github.

Comment: I don't know why but the photo isn't saved anywahere in the device

Comment: I did some modification on my code , please check my sample again , you can find the pic in gallery.

Comment: Still not saving in gallery

Comment: It is weird , works fine on my side . Check the permission in settings if the application allows storage permission .

Comment: I checked it. But no luck

Comment: Remove the try catch block to check if exception throws .